# Entering data into 2 MySql tables with a php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to enter data into 2 tables with one form.

here is my code so far

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Please work!!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $name = addslashes ($_POST['name']);
}
else
{
   $emp_name = $_POST['name'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users, cseason".
       "(name) ".
       "VALUES('$name')";
mysql_select_db('pool');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">player name</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="add player">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many ways but having a issue with the line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users, cseason".
```

i get the following error

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' cseason(name) VALUES('twat')' at line 1
```

I am not sure what direction to go now as i am using this as a learning project

---

This seams to work ill update the part i have changed please advise me if this approach is ok?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users, cseason".
       "(name) ".
       "VALUES('$name')";
mysql_select_db('pool');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```

to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users".
       "(name) ".
       "VALUES('$name')";
mysql_select_db('pool');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO cseason".
       "(name) ".
       "VALUES('$name')";
mysql_select_db('pool');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql2, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```

Comment: you cannot insert into two tables at once with one insert statement. use two statements instead.

Comment: You would need to submit two queries. Also, take a look at transactions.

Comment: i really thank you for your replys but i have found away could you guys tell me if this is right? i have updated my question with the code im using.

Comment: *"but i have found away"* --- If you found a way, then everything's ok. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes and it seems fine. @DeepakBhattarai gave me the major clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code line

```
mysql_select_db('pool');
```

to

```
mysql_select_db("pool",$conn)
```

Comment: can i ask why? what is the difference, im only asking as like i stated above in the oq i am using this as a learning project :)

Comment: you have to define connection with database too. There is another method is,

$con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,"pool");